# android mysql php CSV database

Tags: php, android, mysql, csv

I have created one program which insert user data in `mysql`, but now want to generate report from this `mysql` database to `csv` file.

Please assist me, how to do this?

Comment: so ? what you want us to do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM <the table name>
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/table.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

use the query to get the whole table to a output csv file